# Apache mod_auth_form how to lock down a folder

Tags: apache, authentication

It seems to me that I have a fundamental misunderstanding how "mod_auth_form" is supposed to work. I refer to this page of the Apache documentation:

```
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_auth_form.html
```

I have a public folder and a private folder

What I want to achieve is that a folder is locked down. The users will need to sign in with their user name and password to see the index.php page of my protected folder.

Here is my virtual host setup:

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
    ServerName customform.uwe
    DocumentRoot "/home/uwe/www/protected_custom_form"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/protected_custom_form.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/protected_custom_form.access.log combined

    <Directory "/home/uwe/www/protected_custom_form">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/uwe/www/protected_custom_form/secret/">

    </Directory>

    <Location /dologin>
        SetHandler form-login-handler
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation http://customform.uwe/login.html
        AuthFormProvider file
        AuthUserFile /home/uwe/www/conf/passwd
        AuthType form
        AuthName realm
        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my login form which is hosted in the public folder of my virtual server:

```
<form method="POST" action="/dologin">
    Username: <input type="text" name="httpd_username" value="" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="httpd_password" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="httpd_location" value="http://customform.uwe/secret/index.php" />
</form>
```

OK, here is what happens

1. going to 'customform.uwe' works nicely -> I see my index page for this folder being displayed
2. going to 'customform.uwe/login.html' -> I see my login form coming up and I can sign in and am redirected to my 'index' page of my secret 'folder'
3. going to 'customform.uwe/secret/index.php' show me my index pagge signed in or not.

Here my question:

1. How do protect my secret folder so that a not signed in user is being redirected to the login form.
2. Is this the right approach altogether?

I am really banging my head against the wall at the moment, so thanks a lot for your help.

---

OK, I believe I have got it sorted now. I must have got a bit confused :-)

The idea I followed includes two things:

1. Provide a log in functionality
2. If a user goes to a page where he/she needs to be authenciated - and he/she is not - redirect the user to the login page

To achieve that I needed to edit two files:

1. My Virtual Host
2. My login file

This is the Virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost  *:80>
    ServerName customform.uwe
    DocumentRoot "/home/uwe/www/protected_custom_form"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/protected_custom_form.error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/protected_custom_form.access.log combined

    #This is the public
    <Directory "/home/uwe/www/protected_custom_form">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    #This is the login handler, the login form needs to pint to this handler in its action! 
    <Location /dologin>
       SetHandler form-login-handler
       AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation http://customform.uwe/login.html
       AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation http://customform.uwe/secret/secretindex.php
       AuthFormProvider file
       AuthUserFile /home/uwe/www/conf/passwd
       AuthType form
       AuthName realm
       Session On
       SessionCookieName session path=/
       SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
    </Location>

    # This is the location setting I missed earlier: When a 
    # user comes to this location unauthorised, he will be redirect to the login form
    # This happens as the ErrorDoucment gets overwritten with login page

    <Location /secret/index.php>
        Require valid-user
        AuthFormProvider file
        ErrorDocument 401 /login.html
        AuthUserFile /home/uwe/www/conf/passwd
        AuthType form
        AuthName realm
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation http://customform.uwe/login.html
        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase secret

    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the login form html 
The change in here is that the action handler of the form is now pointing to my location 
which I defined above

```
<form method="POST" action="/dologin">
    Username: <input type="text" name="httpd_username" value="" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="httpd_password" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="httpd_location" value="/secret/secretindex.php" />
</form>
```

This seems to work, it was all (more or less) in the Apache documentation, but I got confused as their is no complete example

Comment: Thank you sir! I spent two days trying to get the wretched form_auth to work without success. There's plenty documentation, but like you said, they require the user to fill in certain 'gaps' inbetween all by themselves, and makes no mention of such gap.