# Sharing Apache Authorization for other virtual hosts in the same machine

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authorization, virtualhost

I have a Debian based Web Server, with a Master Virtual Host on port 80. Here I generate a set of users for AuthType Basic.

```
    <Directory /var/www/example/public_html>
            AuthType Basic
            AuthName "Protected Zone"
            AuthUserFile /var/www/.protected/.passwd_collection
            Require valid-user
            Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
```

After an user had done the access successfully, it must being accessible to other Virtual Hosts in the same machine but different ports (eg. 8081, 8082, and so on).

How can I share the Authorization from port 80 to other Virtual Hosts?

Comment: You can use the same Directory syntax inside VirtualHost 8001 and 8002 or configure Directory at global level in httpd.conf

Comment: @Pandurang I want the user made access only on port 80, then in other virtualhosts the access must be guaranteed;

Comment: You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180119/apache-mod-auth-form-how-to-lock-down-a-folder answer. This will store user name and password information in the session but not sure how it will work.

Comment: I don’t think the _browser_ will let you do that - different ports mean it will see this as a separate “site” to login to, so the user _will_ be presented with the credentials dialog again, when accessing a different VH via a different port.